# forwarding AND sniffing events through an overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I am trying to create an attention bubble around the pointer by tracking mousemove events in an overlay.
All mouse events should then fall through to the DOM elements below the overlay.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    let idle_after = 0;

    setInterval( function () {
        if (Date.now() > idle_after) {
            $('#dot').hide();
        }
    }, 1000 );

    $('#overlay').on( 'mousemove', function (evt) {
        let x = evt.clientX, y = evt.clientY;
        $('#overlay').hide();
        let o = document.elementFromPoint( x, y );
        console.log( o.nodeName );
        $(document).trigger( 'mousemove', evt );    //  <====  this is not working
        $('#overlay').show();
        $('#dot').css( { left: evt.clientX - 20, top: evt.clientY - 20 } ).show();
        idle_after = Date.now() + 2000;
    });

});
```

The **#dot** is the bubble.  The **console.log()** message shows the correct object below the overlay, and bubble moves as intended.  The **trigger()** does not appear to be working.  Other mouse events, like **click**, are blocked as well.  Setting **pointer-events: none;** on the overlay disables everything I am trying to do.

These attempts failed too:

```
        //$(document).trigger( 'mousemove', new Event( 'mousemove', { pageX: x, pageY: y } ) );
        //$(document).trigger( evt );
        //o.dispatchEvent( evt );
        //o.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'mousemove', { pageX: x, pageY: y } ) );
```

The overlay and bubble css:

```
            #overlay {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
            #dot {
                position: absolute;
                width: 10vh;
                height: 10vh;
                border: 1px solid red;
                border-radius: 6vh;
                background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.15 );
            }
```

As an aside, how should I set the offset to center the bubble on the pointer given that I am using vh units to size the bubble?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than update or remove the question, I'm showing the solution here for contrast:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    let idle_after = 0;

    setInterval( function () {
        if (Date.now() > idle_after) $('#dot').hide();
    }, 1000 );

    $(document).on( 'mousemove', function (evt) {
        let x = evt.pageX, y = evt.pageY;
        $('#dot').css( { left: x - 20, top: y - 20 } ).show();
        idle_after = Date.now() + 2000;
    });

});
```

The key is to capture the mousemove events on the **document** (not on the overlay), and then, yes, to set **pointer-events: none;** on the overlay css.

This does not seem to work over any part of the page that has an IFRAME, for security reasons I assume.